# Can CORS work with same-domain requests?

Tags: javascript, cors

Can CORS work with same-origin requests, even though it can be used for cross-origin ones as well? If so, how? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want achieve by using CORS on the same-origin? I can't think of any reason to do so.

Comment: Please look up [what CORS is and how it works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Send a message to another webpage on the same origin

Comment: @Lexica98 and... why not use regular AJAX for that?

Comment: How could you send a message to another document on the same origin...is postMessage useful in that regard?

Comment: The answer is yes, but there is no purpose.

Comment: @Lexica98 uhh... CORS cannot be used to communicate between two pages. Its purpose is to talk to servers other than the one that sent the page that tries to communicate.

Comment: Well, say I had a purpose. http://www.example.com/a.html to http://www.example.com/b.html. How would it work? I guess that's another question

Comment: @Lexica98 `postMessage` communicates between two pages = specific documents residing in specific web browser (the same one). AJAX lets such a page talk to a web server, by requesting a response the same way that browsers do when requesting a page. The target URL being talked to does not reside in any browser, then (and the response normally isn't an HTML page).

Comment: When I used postMessage, this is what happened: I sent the message to my iframe.contentWindow, with the src as the other website etc, but this message was only visible in the iframe of the document that posted the message in the first place. The actual content of the iframe seemed to be the same when I looked at the web page hosting it. I don't know how to get around this

Comment: @Lexica98 if you need help debugging your iFrame code or using `postMessage`, then that's a very different question from this. If you need help debugging your code, we need to see that code. If you need help using `postMessage`, please read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) first. Also, you don't need `postMessage` to talk to same-origin pages. You can access their global scope directly (`postMessage` might still be cleaner).

Comment: Well, I'll look into directly accessing global scope with regard to web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy prevents JavaScript from reading HTTP responses from other origins.

CORS provides a way for an origin to make an exception to that policy so that JavaScript *can* read the response.

If you are making a request to the same origin then the same origin policy will allow it in the first place, so you don't need an exception and so you don't need CORS.

Having CORS HTTP headers in the response won't do any harm though.

Comment: If the CORS header exists and doesn't explicitly allow own origin, does that block same-origin requests?

Comment: Well, I only need the same origin policy actually, as I don't require any cross-origin requests. But I don't actually know how to use this to exchange info between two web pages on the same domain. How would that work?

Comment: @JanDvorak — [No](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/20777222/index.php).

Comment: @Lexica98 — There are plenty of introductory Ajax tutorials out there. Stackoverflow isn't the place to write another one. (It falls under the headings of "too broad" and "insufficient research").